# Socket-io Client Not connecting

Tags: swift, socket.io

I installed the swift-socketio-client from the Swift Package Manager, and when I try to connect:

```
let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:3000")!, config: [.log(true)])
let defaultNamespaceSocket = manager.defaultSocket
let socket = manager.socket(forNamespace: "/message")

socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
    print("socket connected")
}

socket.connect()
```

Using a simulator, not a physical device.

**The Log:**

```
LOG SocketIOClient{/message}: Adding handler for event: connect
LOG SocketIOClient{/message}: Handling event: statusChange with data: [connecting, 2]
LOG SocketIOClient{/message}: Joining namespace /message
LOG SocketManager: Tried connecting socket when engine isn't open. Connecting
LOG SocketManager: Adding engine
LOG SocketManager: Manager is being released
LOG SocketIOClient{/message}: Client is being released
LOG SocketEngine: Starting engine. Server: http://127.0.0.1:3000
LOG SocketEngine: Handshaking
LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Client is being released
LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&EIO=4
LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got polling response
LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got poll message: 0{"sid":"tLgrfJ8T1cQKPms8AAAJ","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000,"maxPayload":100000000}
LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 0{"sid":"tLgrfJ8T1cQKPms8AAAJ","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000,"maxPayload":100000000}
LOG SocketEngine: Engine is being released
nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C2] Client called nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint on unconnected nw_connection
nw_connection_copy_connected_remote_endpoint_block_invoke [C2] Client called nw_connection_copy_connected_remote_endpoint on unconnected nw_connection
```

I can't really see what went wrong, but my API doesn't log any new connections, and the connected function doesn't run.

Any reasons why this doesn't work?

Tested in Postman, and the URL is valid.

Comment: you could try `https:` as usually required by Apple/Swift. Else, adjust your NSAppTransportSecurity in your Info.plist for using `http:`

Comment: set Allow Arbitrary Loads to true, and still not working

Comment: as I understand `Postman` can generate some sort of Swift code for you, this may help trackdown your problem.